# Find average of computed values with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm trying to get the difference between two times off of each date in percentage (got that down) and then add all the percentages up and get the average but I couldn't figure out how to. The data is pulled from JSON. Any ideas? Help is much appreciated.

This is the html:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController as main">
<section class="view">
    <h1>Stuff</h1>
        <ul class="stuff">
            <li ng-repeat="item in main.logs">
            <p>{{$index + 1}}</p>
                <p>{{ item.date }}</p>
                <p>{{ main.logs.calc(item.start, item.loggedIn) }} %</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
</section>
</div>
```

app.js file

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'MainController'
]);
```

controller, what I have so far:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
 .controller('MainController', ['$http', function($http){

    var checklog = this;

    checklog.logs = [];

    $http.get('./login.json').success(function(data){
        checklog.logs = data;

        checklog.logs.calc = function(d1, d2) {
            checklog.logs.percent = [];

            var d1 = new Date(d1).getTime();
            var d2 = new Date(d2).getTime();
            var diff = ( ((d2 - d1) / 60000) / 60 ) * 100 ;

            checklog.logs.percent = 100 - Math.floor(diff);

            return checklog.logs.percent;
        }
    });
}]);
```

JSON is something like this:

```
[{  
    "date"      : "2015-09-15",
    "start"     : "2015-09-15 17:00:00+10",
    "loggedIn"  : "2015-09-15 17:06:27+10",
}]
```

Comment: You should not be modifying the properties of `checklogs.logs` because it is an array.  Instead modify properties of `checklog` itself.

Comment: Alternatively, you can iterate through the array and modify the properties properties of `checklogs.logs[i]` if you want additional properties for each item element.